# How to find the Second value from a table.?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have One table with StatusID in StatusHistory Table. One customer could be multiple statusID. I need to find just previous statusID that mean the second Status ID  which just befor he was hold.

I am getting current one this bellow way:

```
SELECT top 1 StatusIDHeld
FROM dbo.UserStatusHistory
WHERE userid=2154
ORDER BY tatusChangedOn DESC
```

**Question:**

I need 2nd statusID means just previous statusID

How to find the Second value(StatusID) from a table.?

Comment: What database engine: sql server. postgresql, mysql, access database?

Comment: I am using `sql server 2008 R2`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing like second value of table. It depends on many factors, like indexes, etc.

To be able to get 1., 2. or n-th record depending on sort order, use [ROW_NUMBER()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx) function.

```
SELECT StatusIDHeld 
FROM
(
    SELECT StatusIDHeld, ROW_NUMBER () OVER(ORDER by StatusIDHeld) as RowNo
    FROM UserStatusHistory
) AS t
where t.RowNo = 2
```

Another way is to use TOP instruction twice:

```
SELECT TOP(1) StatusIDHeld
FROM (
    SELECT TOP(2) StatusIDHeld
    FROM UserStatusHistory
    WHERE userid=2154
    ORDER BY tatusChangedOn ASC
) AS t
ORDER BY StatusIDHeld DESC
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. Your 1st one is working fine but 2nd one not working ...

Comment: It's just an example. You need to change it to your needs, based on your logic.

Comment: `SELECT TOP(1) StatusIDHeld
FROM (
    SELECT TOP(2) StatusIDHeld
    FROM UserStatusHistory
    WHERE userid=1037146
    ORDER BY statusChangedOn DESC
) AS t
ORDER BY StatusIDHeld ASC`

Comment: Is this mean that you found a proper query? If yes, then CONGRATS!

Comment: Yes , just i have changed order By ... Thanks again :)

Answer (score 4):

```
select StatusIDHeld 
from
(select 
    StatusIDHeld,
    ROW_NUMBER () over (order by tatusChangedOn DESC) as num
from dbo.UserStatusHistory
where userid=2154
) T
where T.num = 2
```

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this is to fetch the first 2, and then take the second one of them:

```
select top 1 StatusIDHeld from (
  select top 2 StatusIDHeld, StatusChangedOn 
  from dbo.UserStatusHistory 
  order by StatusChangedOn DESC
) TMP order by StatusChangedOn ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to offset your query reset by 1.

Please try this:

```
select StatusIDHeld from dbo.UserStatusHistory order by tatusChangedOn DESC Limit 1 OFFSET 1;
```

Comment: Not applicable to sql server.

Comment: The Offset fetch is only available from SQL Server 2012 onwards